# create dynamic grid with drop down

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a dynamic gridview with first row as drop down on clicking edit button. I dont have any idea on how to start. Can you please help. I have gone through some articals and found using the InstantiateIn method we can achieve.

```
public class CreateItemTemplate : ITemplate
    {
        //Field to store the ListItemType value
        private ListItemType myListItemType;

        public CreateItemTemplate(ListItemType item)
        {
            myListItemType = item;
        }

        public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
        {
            //Code to create the ItemTemplate and its field.
            if (myListItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
                TextBox txtCashCheque = new TextBox();
                container.Controls.Add(txtCashCheque);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this for a single instance of a grid on a page, or are you creating a re-usable control?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display this on a single page, you should not be creating a server control.

Use the grid's TemplateField.

Note: if you are using AutoGenerateColumns = true, just add the column to the grid markup. It will be added first.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList id="someId" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="One" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="twO" />
         </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

you may need to provide more information about what you want to do wth this drop down (does it need a default value?).
Based on your needs, you may be able to do this in markup, or, you may need to use a grid event.

- Brian
  UPDATE: adding event handler

if you set onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated" in the grid

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
        onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
```

and do this in your code behind:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var dropdown = e.Row.FindControl("someId") as DropDownList;
            //dropdown.DataSource= <>; bind it
            //dropdown.SelectedValue =<>"; / set value how you would 
        }
    }
```

you can manipulate the drop down ad it gets created.
If it cannot fin the controls look in each cell: e.Row.Cells[[index]].FindControl(""someId"")

Comment: In this case the entire column will become drop down right? I am using AutoGenerateColumns = true . only that grid gets populated with datatable datas

Comment: in this case you wil have added a new column that is a only a drop down. adding event handler sample